# how to get the RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding in javascript/react to generate a key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cryptography, rsa, cryptojs

I need to generate a key with the algorithm RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding to send to the server to retrieve data, The server accepts only the key with this algorithm. The server is written in Java, and there is such an algorithm in Java.

But in javascript, in the documentation, in the list of algorithms this algorithm is missing, is there any solution?

You can see examples here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/generateKey

And this is a list of Node js algorithms where also missing. https://nodejs.org/api/webcrypto.html#algorithm-matrix

I tried with different packages that generate the key, I tried without packages, with webAPI SubtleCrypto.generateKey() methods but without results.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to generate a key with the algorithm RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding

First of all: forget about that ECB. ECB mode is the use of a cipher multiple times for subsequent parts of the plaintext message. However, Java only allows for a single invocation per message. It should have read `"None"` for the mode.

The `"PKCS1Padding"` is a padding that is performed on the plaintext message. It is required to have a secure padding as "textbook RSA" - i.e. basic modular exponentiation - is not secure. However, *the key itself is only used for the modular exponentiation*, which is the same for any RSA operation regardless of the padding.

There simply is no such thing as a specific key for PKCS#1 padding; you can use any genericly generated RSA key. Maybe your Java provider *accepts* that algorithm string `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"` for the call to `KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(String alg)` instance, but it will just default to `"RSA"`, and you can do the same within JavaScript.

When you **use** the resulting key for encryption you should then probably use PKCS#1 v1.5 compatible padding, as this is what `"PKCS1Padding"` means in Java. In never versions of the standard OAEP is also defined, so the algorithm string in Java is by now thoroughly antiquated and - well - wrong. No API will nor should contain these kind of algorithm strings unless they explicitly want to copy the Java API.

Note that sometimes *certificates* that contain a public key will also indicate an algorithm and this could include a padding mode. But that's a different topic; I just mention it because sometimes the term "certificate" and "public key" manage to get confused somehow.